# Couchbase not working in Asp.net

Tags: couchbase

I installed Cachebase Server on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1 installed, with default setup.

Now, i am trying to test the server, and is not working. This is what i have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration();
        config.Urls.Add(new Uri("http://192.168.1.4:8091/pools/default"));
        config.Bucket = "default";
        var client = new CouchbaseClient(config);

        // this line of code takes about 10-15 seconds to execute, and always returns false
        bool result = client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "key_10", "value to save", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // this line of code always returns null
        var savedValue = client.Get("key_10");
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong? I don't think it has anything to do with firewall, because when i access the url in a browser, it returns me a Json object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to remove the `/default` from the url.

Try `config.Urls.Add(new Uri("http://192.168.1.4:8091/pools"));`

Comment: I've removed the "/default" and still has the same behavior

Comment: Is there a password for the bucket?

Comment: I don't think so. I've used defaults on the installer, and the only place it asked me for a password was for the Web Configurator. Can i check if the bucket has a password?

Comment: Yes.  Launch the couchbase console, go to the Data Buckets tab, click the arrow to the left of the bucket, click 'edit' on the right hand side, under access control there if it's set to standard port there is a password section below

Comment: Is set on Standard port (TCP port 11211. ASCII protocol or Binary auth-less)

Comment: Ha I hate when you spend a long time and then a restart fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app on the server or another machine? You are mentioning the Firewall so I guess you have ensured the correct ports are opened as described [here](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-bestpractice-secondfirewall.html)

The reason why I'm asking is because I do think there's a handshake being done using HTTP and then it changes protocol. If that is the case, you might need the other ports to be opened if you access it from another computer.